# If WordPress Repeater has 1 field, 2 fields etc else

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater that I would like to alter based on how many fields it out puts

the code I have for the basic repater:

```
<?php // REAPEATER FIELD
if(get_field('whatever')): ?>
  <?php while(has_sub_field('whatever')): ?>

    <div class="whatever_block">
      <?php the_sub_field('anything'); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How I want it to look:

```
<?php // REAPEATER FIELD
if(get_field('whatever')): ?>
  <?php while(has_sub_field('whatever')): ?>

    //if only one
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <?php the_sub_field('anything'); ?>
    </div>

    //if only two
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <?php the_sub_field('anything'); ?>
    </div>

    //if etc

    //else
    <div class="whatever_block">
      <?php the_sub_field('anything'); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How I can achieve the above above output with if statements? are if statements even the correct way to go?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Celeo , i was just updating my questions while you were commenting.  I am trying to achieve the 2nd version (how i want it to look).  So I was thinking with an if-statement i would change the class of what im outputting based on how many items there are.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of fields that can be active at a time? Like in ACF, did you set a Max number?

Comment: @Joe, yes I set the max number to be 4

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this uses the count() function to count the fields, then use a switch case to set a class for your div, like this:

```
<?php // REAPEATER FIELD
if(get_field('whatever')): ?>
    <?php switch(count(get_field('whatever'))) :    //checks total fields set
        case '1':
            $divClass = 'oneField';
            break;
        case '2':
            $divClass = 'twoField';
            break;
        case '3':
            $divClass = 'threeField';
            break;
        case '4':
            $divClass = 'fourField';
            break;
    endswitch; ?>
    <?php while(has_sub_field('whatever')): ?>

        <div class="<?php echo $divClass; ?>">
          <?php the_sub_field('anything'); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just replace 'oneField', 'twoField', ect with your desired class names, and you should be set.

Comment: If you tried my answer, I found a few minor code issues that I just fixed in an edit, so this code should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `count` on the repeater to check how many sub fields it has. Here is a solution using the ACF v4.xx [`have_rows` syntax](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) (should nevertheless work with `get_field` as well):

```
if( have_rows( 'parent_whatever' ) ) {
    $posts_no = get_field( 'parent_whatever' );
    while( have_rows( 'parent_whatever' ) {
        the_row();
        $class = "col-sm-" . 12/$posts_no;

        echo '<div class="' . $class . '">';
        the_sub_field( 'whatever' );
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
endif;
```